# InfoPath 2013 - select specific checkbox after select item from droplist

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online, custom-list, list-form, infopath-rules

I try to modify form (SharePoint 2013 Online) using InfoPath 2013 to select check-box after select item on a drop list.
I have two lists: Clients and Job List. On Clients I put client name and select this check box's DMA, DWP, DMG.

On Job List I want to create item only for those Clients, that have select specific check box on Clients list.

How its should work:
After create element I can choose Client from drop list - this list has reference to Client list by Name field. After I choose Client, the check box's in this form **should select the same check box** such as is highlighted in the list of Clients.

I have try to do rule on Client field (on Job List):

*When DMA (on Clients) = True then set field value DMA_J = True

When DMA (on Clients) = True then set field value DMA_J = DMA (from Clients list)*


Please help. Maybe XPath can help, but I don't know this language.